# How to display different views / HTML pages dependent on user?

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, administrator

I am building a simple `Web application` using [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

I would like to display a different `views` for:

- Administrators
- Standard users

*How* can I do this? I ask as `Administrators` will be able to carry out different functionalities and see extra `buttons` etc as standard users.

Administrators will be given extra privileges/permissions, possibly identified using a `flag` in the `oracle` database.

For reference, I am also using [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) and [Thyme leaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) within the application.

Comment: This is very open question. Try to find some online tutorials like http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-role-based-login-example/ or http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thymeleaf has been integrated with spring security provides us concerte base for working with the requirment such as you ask.

[Click here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html) for tutorials and guide. This guide also has link for spring security documentation if you are interested reading with.

1) Spring security - Will decide eligible user roles after validating the user table using userId. Example, If a User eligible for 'ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER' roles, could able to see below 2 buttons after loggin in.

2) Example Thymeleaf code after authorize role has been set.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  //show the save button  
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
  //show the view button
</div>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thank you, so essentially I dont need to create different views, just use spring security within the views to show or not show buttons etc?